# How to add xlwings to VBA reference automatically from python side

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlwings

To activate UDFs on excel book, we need `Tools` > `References` > check `xlwings` as shown in https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html

I would like to know is there any way to do this automatically from python side?

```py
import xlwings as xw
def test():    
    wb = xw.books.add()
    # wanna add something here to edit VBA reference.
    wb.save("test.xlsm")
```

I expect it's possible because xlwings-quick-start can(maybe this is done by batch).

Answer (score 0):

Seems following will work:

```py
if "xlwings" not in [i.Name for i in wb.api.VBProject.References]:
    xlam_path = os.path.expanduser('~') + "\\anaconda3\\" + env_name
    xlam_path += "\\lib\\site-packages\\xlwings\\addin\\xlwings.xlam"
    wb.api.VBProject.References.AddFromFile(xlam_path)
```

but if there are better ways, pls tell me.